# Canvas feature for Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Is there a canvas feature for NS?

I'd like this specifically for ios..my application calls for a custom drawing a full view. Paint background, draw lines, text etc.

I looked at some questions - but most seem quite old.

Comment: In my opinion you could use nativescript-canvas plugin. You could find the plugin and demo in this Github repo - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-canvas

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. Basically curious how the Telerik Chart and calendar controls are implemented. I'd like to do similar - have access to a drawing surface - on both platforms.

Comment: I can't seem to install this plug-in. Did "tns plugin add nativescript-canvas" and getting 404 error. Any help appreciated? Would also appreciate a response to my previous comment.

Comment: There is a blog post on medium with a playground sample in the comments by Tiago Alves on how to do this https://medium.com/@info_25865/how-to-create-a-canvas-in-nativescript-90c47b067b4b